# How to use SO more effectively tagging questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

At times I see questions to which I do not have the answer, but I'd like to see the answer from others, because the question is relevant to my work, too. I noticed that when I answer or comment I do get notification when somebody responds. Very nice feature. I am wondering if I can tag a question somehow to be able to follow the answers and comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the question as a favourite. You will be informed in your profile whenever new answers arrive to the question.